Is $n^{\alpha}$ mod $1$ dense in $[0,1]$?
It is a well known result that if $\alpha$ is irrational, then $\{n\cdot{\alpha} \text{ mod }1 :n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$. I am wondering if there is a similar result for whether $\{n^{\alpha} \text{ mod }1 :n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense. I have considered taking some logarithm transform by writing $ n^\alpha = 10^{\alpha \log_{10} n} $, and investigate the density of $\alpha \log_{10} n$
, but I find it challenging to conclude how density of one implies another.
In fact, I believe that $\alpha$ does not need to be irrational for this set to be dense, by running a couple of numerical simulations, it appears that as long as $\alpha$ is not an integer, the result is always dense (but not uniformly distributed, so tools like Weyl's Criterion might not help).
Any help/suggestion of direction are appreciated.
Edit: The following is a simulation for $\alpha=3/2$, with $n=100,200,500,1000$. The horizontal axis is the interval $[0,1]$, and each vertical line marks the appearance of a number. The "density so far" is defined to be the maximum distance between consecutive marks.


If $\alpha\neq 0$ and $\sigma > 0$ is not an integer then $(\alpha\cdot n^\sigma)$ is uniformly distributed mod $1$. See Uniform distribution of sequences by Kuipers, Niederreiter exercise 3.9. So we just need $\sigma$ to not be negative or an integer.

You said its not uniformly distributed and Weyl criterion or other tools don't help - that's clearly wrong as per above.
